# Pandas 'Incorrect information in file' using to_sql Method

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I have a pandas dataframe and am writing to a SQL database via this code:

```
df.to_sql(con=conn, name='temp', if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

It throws the following error. I'm wondering what this error means, why its getting displayed, and how do I fix it?:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/2_distance.py", line 129, in 
>       df.to_sql(con=conn, name='temp', if_exists='replace',index=False)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1362, in to_sql
>       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 471, in to_sql
>       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1150, in to_sql
>       table.create()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 586, in create
>       if self.exists():
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 574, in exists
>       return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1178, in has_table
>       schema or self.meta.schema,
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1534, in run_callable
>       return callable_(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1700, in has_table
>       skip_user_error_events=True).execute(st)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 939, in execute
>       return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1097, in _execute_text
>       statement, parameters
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
>       context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
>       exc_info
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
>       reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
>       context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1033, "Incorrect information in file: './pickaresk/temp.frm'") [SQL: 'DESCRIBE `temp`']

Comment: Likely table corruption: https://serverfault.com/questions/422507/mysql-incorrect-information-in-file-corrupt-error

Comment: Are you sure you have a table `temp` already defined?  A `.frm` file is created when a table is created (`./pickaresk/temp.frm`) but Pandas is having trouble identifying the table schema.